# Can I apply for a visitor visa for UK while on a Working Holiday Visa within the country?

Tags: united-kingdom, uk-visa, canadian-citizens, working-holiday-visas, uk-visitor-visa

I am a Canadian, on a working holiday visa in the UK. The expiry of my working holiday visa is April 25th. Can I apply for a visitor visa to activate when my working holiday expires? What is the easiest way to go about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no mechanism to change your immigration status from Tier 5 to visitor from within the UK. You will need to exit and re-enter as a visitor. As a Canadian you are eligible to stay for up to 6 months visa-free, however if you return soon after your Tier 5 visa ends you should be prepared to prove that you fulfil the Immigration Rules relating to visitors, in particular V4.2 (a) will leave the UK at the end of their visit. https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-appendix-v-visitor-rules

See also https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/100662/my-tier-5-youth-mobility-expired-2-months-ago-can-i-re-enter-the-uk-as-a-touri/100667#100667